# Clip angle degrees to a range

Tags: angle, degrees

I have a function that returns an angle. However, sometimes the returned value (degrees) is negative, or it is below 0, or it is greater than 360.

How do I clip the returned value so that it is always between 0 and 360, and is always positive? Do I use the modulo function for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could, indeed, use modulo, at the only condition that your wanted range doesn't include 360°. The range would therefore be *[0°, 360°[*.

Comment: That's fine. Does it work okay with negative numbers?

Comment: I guess you just have to add 360 at the end.